# Body exceeded 1mb limit error in Next.js API route

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, next.js, multipartform-data

If I use `FormData` on Next.js to upload image to server I always get this error.

I tried a lot but I didn't fix this.

My code:

```js
const changeValue = (e) => {
if (e.target.name === "avatar") {
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("image", file, file.name);
      try {
        const config = {
          Headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        };
        axios
          .post("/api/upload", formData, config)
          .then((res) => {
            setAvatar(res.data);
            setAvatarPreview(res.data);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

##### API routes in `page` router

The default size limit for the body parser is `1mb` in API routes. You can modify this value through the [custom `config` object](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#custom-config) exported from the API route.

```js
// /pages/api/upload.js

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: {
            sizeLimit: '2mb' // Set desired value here
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there's a limit imposed on the API routes body size, see [How to override the 4mb API Routes body size limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503440/how-to-override-the-4mb-api-routes-body-size-limit) for details.

---

##### Server Actions in `app` router

The same default size limit of `1mb` is applied to Server Actions. You can modify this value using the [`serverActions.bodySizeLimit`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/serverActions#bodysizelimit) option in `next.config.js`.

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
    serverActions: {
        bodySizeLimit: '2mb' // Set desired value here
    }
}
```

Comment: I set 4.5mb, still I face the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75527356/why-vercel-does-not-process-a-body-with-1-5mb-size

Comment: @János See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70504864/1870780.

Comment: Finally I started to use AWS Lambda as an alternative, right, there is no ither trick?!

Comment: this is not working for me. nextjs version: 13.2.4

Comment: @ManjunathGk The above solution is for `pages` API routes. The new `app` router introduced in Next.js 13 doesn't seem to support it. See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers.

Comment: app router now has global option for `serverActions.bodySizeLimit`; https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/serverActions#bodysizelimit

Answer (score 0):

My application is frontended by nginx so I had to change `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file to allow upload files up to 10mb.

```
http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    ...
}
```