# Forwarding multipart/form-data using NextJS api

Tags: javascript, express, proxy, next.js, multipartform-data

I am having a bit of trouble forwarding `multipart/form-data` using NextJS api.

```js
async function proxy(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> {
    const { body, headers, method, url } = req;
    
    // Doing some work to handle authentication

    const rewriteUrl = url?.replace('/api/proxy', '');

    const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        url: rewriteUrl,
        method: method as Method,
        headers: {
            cookie: '',
            Authorization: token,
        },
        data: body,
    };

    try {
        const { data: originalData, status } = await axiosInstance(config);
        return res.status(status).json(originalData);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(err.status).json(err);
    }
}

export default proxy;
```

When calling the API directly or using non `multipart/form-data` network calls, no problem whatsoever. However, when proxying a `multipart/form-data`, I am receiving `413 Payload Too Large`

[image: request payload]
[image: request header]

I am have been trying to use

```js
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};
```

but in that case the backend API is responding with `400` telling that the file doesn't exist.

As am I adding an authentication header before forwarding the request, can this be the culprit as the content size change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Body exceeded 1mb limit error in Next.js API route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68574254/body-exceeded-1mb-limit-error-in-next-js-api-route)

Comment: any updates on this?? I see the reason that the reason it says file doesn't exist is because the file exists as multipart data which is not parsed by `body-parser` and should use packages like `formidable` or `multer` for it.