# How to override the 4mb API Routes body size limit?

Tags: next.js

I have tried several ways to override the API Routes body size limit.

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/api-routes-body-size-limit

- Setting up a custom server (Basic Express App)
- Pass the custom config for bodyParser sizeLimit on the route in question.

```js
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: '10mb',
    },
  },
}
```

I have some db responses that are over 7mb in size and am looking to be able to support responses this big.  I am deployed to AWS and not Vercel, and I am not using serverless functions.

What am I missing to accomplish this so I don't keep getting that `exceeds 4MB. This will cause the request to fail in a future version` error message on the backend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not because of Vercel / AWS. It's by design of Next.js, unfortunately.

From the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/api-routes-body-size-limit):

> ### Why This Error Occurred
>
> API Routes are meant to respond quickly and are not intended to support responding with large amounts of data. The maximum size of responses is 4 MB.
>
> ### Possible Ways to Fix It
>
> Limit your API Route responses to less than 4 MB. If you need to support sending large files to the client, you should consider using a dedicated media host for those assets. See link below for suggestions.

So basically you're stuck with that 4 megabyte limit, even if you set it otherwise.

You can try to use this [tip to avoid the 5 MB limit](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-bypass-vercel-body-size-limit-serverless-functions).

A tip from me, maybe you can try to build your own API if you really need to support responses that big. [Express](https://expressjs.com/) is a good choice. You can get fine-grained control over your own back-end architecture.

Answer (score 7):

Next.js Docs https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/api-routes-response-size-limit

Feature Added https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/34700

```jsx
export const config = {
  api: {
    responseLimit: false,
    // responseLimit: '8mb',
  },
}
```

***Warning!***  To ensure proper functionality, it is imperative that the config object be exported from the API page, rather than simply set as a property in the next.config.js file.

***Note.*** If you are not using Next.js in a serverless environment, and understand the performance implications of not using a CDN or dedicated media host, you can set this limit to false inside your API Route.

Comment: Warning! it is not `next.config.js` property! `config` should be exported from api page!

Comment: What to do in case I am using the app router config?