# NEXTJS - API fails when sending files

Tags: reactjs, next.js

A while ago I created an upload.js in  /pages/api/upload.js.  It took the uploaded files sent to it and uploaded them to AWS.

Recently its stopped working.  There is no feedback in the console (no matter how many console logs I do) In the terminal or the browser.  So i created a new API, with the following code:

```
   import formidable from "formidable";


export default async function handler(req, res) {

    if (req.method === "POST") {

        console.log('POST')



        return res.status(200).send('Finished POST')

    }

    return res.status(200).send('Hello World')

}

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};
```

A super simple API.  It works, I get the console.logs.  However, when I send a file to the API, even though its not doing anything with it, POSTman just spins and spins.  It just states 'sending request' and never finishes.  There is no console log output, no feedback whatsever.

How can I find out why I cant send files anymore?  What can I do to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your wrong api configuration. You have disabled your body purser. As a result, your API couldn't parse the file. Allow your bodyParser to parse the file from requested body.

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {

    if (req.method === "POST") {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log('POST')
        return res.status(200).send('Finished POST')

    }
    return res.status(200).send('Hello World')
}

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: {
            sizeLimit: '10mb', // change this to a limit of your file size
          },
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I still get the same results.  As i mentioned it recently stopped working, so I think now that it might be something to do with the other librarys that other people have added to the project.

Comment: But I have tested the code in my editor, It is working well. You my try "multer" to upload files.

Comment: Also the documentation for Formidible says to not use the BodyParser and to set it to false.  I've since found that its to do with the filesize of the images I sending, if I send a small one it works but anything over 90kb and it just hangs.

Comment: Hello @RichardBridge ,Got your point. I think you should configure your body parser to a limit. The nextJS has a limit of body. You should extend that. Please take a look on the below two simiar post's and do a test by configuring your api. I have not tested them. So let me know if this solve your problem, then I'll also be aware about this issue in future. 

The related post's:
1)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503440/how-to-override-the-4mb-api-routes-body-size-limit

2)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68574254/body-exceeded-1mb-limit-error-in-next-js-api-route