# I cannot pass a base64 data URL through the Next.js API route but I can pass anything else

Tags: typescript, next.js

This is driving me mad. I have done it before without any issues, and now it just won't work.

It will work if I pass an empty array, a string, a number, or anything else. But as soon as I add the data URL the API does not receive the request and no error is thrown..... nothing... it's like it never happened and the console.log logs the proper data on the client.

I have tried random strings of the same length and even double the length of the base64 data url and it works without issues.

What am I missing?

(I have never done it in Typescript before but I don't think that is the issue)

```
  const saveUpdatedImages = async () => {
    try {
      console.log(updatedImages)
      var res = await fetch("/api/admin/dashboard/saveImages", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updatedImages)
      })
      var result = await res.json();
      if (result.success) {
        //reload page
        window.location.reload();
      } else {
        alert("could not save, try again or talk to Marcus")
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }

  }
```

**
Array looks like this on the console.log:**

```
[
    {
        "imgUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAQwAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA9tYAAQAAAADTLQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAlkZXNjAAAA8AAAAHRyWFlaAAABZAAAABRnWFlaAAABeAAAABRiWFlaAAABjAAAABRyVFJDAAABoAAAAChnVFJDAAABoAAAAChiVFJDAAABoAAAACh3dHB0AAAByAAAABRjcHJ0AAABSHORETENED_FOR_READABILITY_t6//Z",
        "_id": "6348c8139336a9e1fb127965"
    }
]
```

I have tried many different images/base64 data urls and the same result on all.
I have tried to change the .imgUrl to random strings, numbers, and arrays and then it always works.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a server problem. Have you checked the network tab in the Developer Tools panel to see whether the API call is being made? You should be able to inspect whether the request is being sent and (if so) what the response code is.

Comment: did you try to increase the body size limit? see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68591262/18457414

Comment: @mocherfaoui facing the same issue but for base 64. no idea why. its only 150kb. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78149924/nextjs-api-route-ts-stuck-on-await-request-formdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

It is only an issue on localhost; It works as intended once it build it out to Vercel.

No idea why or how‍♂️