# nextJS API route.ts stuck on await request.formData()

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, next.js13

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    const balance = await UserHasBalance();

    console.log("0");
    const formData = await request.formData();
    console.log("1");
stuck on "0"
```

the formdata is below

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryRV59K1PqB5ZoUDBk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="url"

dsfd.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryRV59K1PqB5ZoUDBk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJdPr6eEKMSAwIG9iago8PC9DcmVhdG9yIChDaHJvbWl1bSkKL1Byb2R1Y2VyIChTa2lhL1BERiBtMTE2KQovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlIChEOjIwMjMxMDA2MDcyMDE3KzAwJzAwJykKL01vZERhdGUgKEQ6MjAyMzEwMDYwNzIwMTcrMDAnMDAnKT4+CmVuZG9iagozIDAgb2Jq....huge string
(the file is a base64 of a 100kb pdf file (need to get from localstorage so cant store File))
```

Request headers

```
Accept:
application/json, text/plain, */*

Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br, zstd

Content-Length:
155033

Content-Type:
multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryRV59K1PqB5ZoUDBk
```

When earlier the formdata was a string and a File it used to work normally, so is the length problem?

PS: When the string is stripped down to 15kb it starts to work.

I don't see any other issues in the limit etc variables set anywhere.
Request sent via axios.

Would ideally want to avoid aws s3/presigned url etc or other libraries.

Comment: can you create a codesandbox example?