# Why Next.js / Vercel does not process a body with 1.5MB size?

Tags: next.js, vercel

Based on documentation max request body size is 4.5MB.

then why Vercel refuse a data with 1.5MB?

I also set Next.js limit to 4.5MB:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: "4.5mb", // Set desired value here
    },
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview

```js
import axios from "axios";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { connectToDatabase } from "../../lib/connectToDatabase";

export default async function insertOne(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const { body } = req;
  const { mongoClient } = await connectToDatabase();
  const db = mongoClient.db("datamapper");
  const collection = db.collection("team");

  const teamId = req.query.teamShortId as string;
  const field = req.query.field as string;

  // TODO: Handle teamId also
  try {
    await collection.updateOne(
      { teamId: teamId },
      {
        $push: {
          [`${field}`]: body,
        },
        $set: {
          updatedAt: new Date(),
        },
      },
      { upsert: true }
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  res.status(200).end();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just encountered the same issue and found your question while researching. The `sizeLimit` cannot be set in global config - you have to do it on a per-route basis. This page https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/request-helpers#custom-config talks about exposing it as per-route configuration.

Example:

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: {
      sizeLimit: '10mb',
    },
  },
}

const handler = async (_req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
...
```

Comment: I doubt it work

Comment: Why do you think that? It's tested and works for me on next.js 12.3.4. Without that config, the limit is 1mb. With the config set to `20mb` I was able to upload a 19.7Mb test file.

Comment: I was not able to upload bigger than 1MB.

Answer (score 0):

The limit should be set up in the API route pages. Not in the next.config.js